# Responsive background image?

Tags: css, image, mobile, background, responsive

I am creating a webpage and I am very new to responsive design.
I have a 100% long content area box and I added a background-image on the right side to cover up the whole right half of the content box. On the left I would like to add text and such.

However currently if I bring it to mobile size, the background image shrinks due to my current background size being "50%". Also the text overlaps the image.

What is the best way to do this where I can have text on the left, my image on the right ( covering the content box fully with no margins )

Below is my basic code:

```
<style>
.FirstRow {
  background-image: url("https://miro.medium.com/max/9792/1*-xHF1a7BT8hN8KsHbQCDSw.jpeg"); 
  background-position: right;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 50%;}

.firstrowpad {
  padding-top:0px; 
  height: 50%; 
  padding-bottom:0px;}

.HeaderFont {
  font-size: 2em; 
  left: 15%; 
  top: 15%; 
  position: absolute;}

</style>

<div class="FirstRow firstrowpad">

 <div class="HeaderFont">
    <center>  
     ❝ A dining experience <br>in the comfort of <br>your own home. ❞
     </center>

</div>
</div>
```

I want that when I shrink to mobile, the background image is fully visible without a scrollbar ( but smaller) and the text are collapses beneath it.

I'm also not sure if this is even the best way to implement what I am going for, especially with the text because i'd like to add a background color to the text with a padding and such too.

Thank you for the help.

Jen T

**EDIT:**

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) { /* Specific to this particular image */
  .FirstRow {
    background-size: 100%;
  }
}
```

This fixed the image issue but how do I get the text to collapse beneath?

Thank you

Comment: Try with `background-size: cover`

Comment: Hi, if I do that or 100% yes the image looks right in mobile ( excepting the text overlapping it ) but then the image on a regular screen is too big.

Comment: Take a look a this: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/CSS/Media_queries Using media queries you can provide different styles for different resolutions. Perhaps `contain` in Desktop and `cover` in mobile.

Comment: Yes I am going to edit my post. I got the image to look right, but now how do I get the text to snap below it?